# stay connected with twilio call on page refresh

Tags: php, twilio

i need help to stay connected with the call during conversation. i have used the following code given on twilio Doc.

**PHP Part is here**

```
$token = new Services_Twilio_Capability(TW_ID, TW_TOKEN);
$token->allowClientIncoming($_SESSION['emp_id']);
```

**JS Part:**

```
Twilio.Device.setup("<?php echo $token->generateToken();?>");


$("#call").click(function() {  
  params = { "tocall" : $('#tocall').val()};
  connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
});

$("#hangup").click(function() {  
  Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
});

Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
        $('#status').text('Ready');
        console.log(Twilio.Device.status());
});

Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {                        
        startCall(conn);
});
```

on the page load the the `Twilio.Device.ready()` function make the user login the receive the calls, but the the user refresh the page the call went disconnected, or if user trying to do something like updating the information of client during the conversation getting the call disconnected. Hope you understand.

But now don't have any idea that how to rid this issue. One option i have to use the hash value on the url something like `#status`.

Please help me to give any alternate solution or modifying this code..

Comment: I know this is year old post but Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @bipen I can't exactly remember, i leaved that company. Try to store token in session.

Comment: Any solution on this?

Comment: @AshishDwivedi, Sorry mate, i forgot what I have used because its too much old. But according to current technology I must use the ReactJs and will handle all the requests through Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session for this... 
store the token value in the session.

```
$_SESSION['token']=$your_token;
```

access like this

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['token'];?>
```

Comment: but if you see on the js part `Twilio.Device.ready()` this function making the user ready, is just the token solve the issue?? because i already used this through passing the token through URL

Comment: If you passed in the url it will not stable when page redirect call backs. if you stored in the session it will be available after the page refresh also.

Comment: can you provide some example if possible with the given code??

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options you could take.

- Store the call state on the server, via a POST request to your server when the call connects. Then when the client refreshes the page, push an incoming (the existing) call to the client.
- Use HTML5 localStorage or similar to store the call state on the client. Your JS should check for existence of a call in localStorage when the page loads. If a call exists in this DB, then connect to the same endpoints as before.